# calling different method in same servlet with different url-pattern like jsf in normal servlets

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I was wondering if it could be possible to call different methods in same servlet, via ajax call using different url-pattern

e.g. In Struts we can provide several execute style method giving different patterns for each, similarly we can do for JSF or spring.

But, how can we do it in plain servlets without using any frameworks!

Comment: You can't, except by implementing your own framework on top of servlets. But please, don't do that.

Comment: thanks JB-Nizet, i will definitely do as you said..